# rtk query session id

Tags: reactjs, django, sessionid, rtk-query

I'm hosting a django site locally. If baseQuery has relative path like that `baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/api' })`, then session id is sent inside headers automatically

```
headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')
          }
```

if front-end and back-end parts are hosted on different ports and the path in baseQuery is absolute
`fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api' })`  (while React is running on :3000)
then session id is not attached to requests and Django sends a new one with every response.
Is it normal behaviour and how can it be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's enough to add `credentials: "include"` like that

```
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api', credentials: "include" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try credentials include for private API like this

```
const public = createApi({
 // --
)

const private = createApi({
 credintials: "include"
})
```

Comment: Code-only answers should be updated to explain how the code resolves the question, further guidance can be found in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)